# Wear OS - Simulate pressing button to make screen brighter temporarily

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a wear app which, when notified, opens up and displays an image. I also want the screen brightness to increase temporarily as well, as if I were pressing the button or tapping the screen. Can I do this programmatically? I don't want it to stay bright or change the settings permanently.

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.screenBrightness = 1;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```